# Is the graph $B_{n,r}$, its vertices are all the binary words with $n$ bits, two vertices are connected if they differ exactly in $r$ bits, connected?

Tags: graph-theory

We define the simple graph $B_{n,r}$ where its vertices are all the binary words containing exactly $n$ bits($0,1$), a vertex $a$ is connected with $b$ if they differ exactly in $r$ bits.

**Example:** $n=4, r=2$, the vertices $1100$ and $1111$ are connected.

**Is the graph $B_{1000,400}$ connected?**

**I have tried** to construct $B_{1000,400}$ as a tree with the root $0000\ldots00$, but I couldn't do it because I'm not sure that there is no duplication and that it contains all the $1000$ vertices.

Would you help me please? other ideas than the tree?

Comment: Try a simpler example.  What happens with $B_{4,2}$? Is it connected?  Why or why not? Can you generalize?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: When you move from one vertex to a neighboring vertex, you change the parity of $400$ bits, say $m$ bits from $0$ to $1$ and $400-m$ bits from $1$ to $0$; what does this do to the parity of the number of $1$ bits in the vertex? If that’s not quite enough, mouse over the spoiler-protected block for a further hint.

> Can any sequence of moves take you from $\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{1000}$ to $1\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{999}$?